# Determining Aggregate Roots In Shipping/Receiving Domain

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I am in a bit of analysis paralysis trying to work out my domain and aggregate roots. I have a shipping/receiving and warehousing domain that will eventually expand into a larger erp system for construction type jobs.

The organization has customers and each customer can have various projects. Jobs are scheduled for a specific project and have things like the start date/time, site address and outbound pieces.

The receiving aspect starts with a 3rd party truck arriving that needs to be offloaded.  Based on bill of lading coming in we can determine which one of the organization's end customers/projects this equipment is for.

A lot number is created for that truck and when it is offloaded it results in lot pieces being created. Each lot piece has its own dimensions and weight and each piece could be for any number of projects that the customer has on going with the organization. For the most part each lot will consist of pieces for the same customer project but not always and sometimes we might not know the project the pieces are for until after talking with customer.

At some point in time the customer requests certain lot pieces for a project to be delivered. So a job is created for the project and the lot pieces requested are assigned to that job,

The day before a job a dispatcher will look at the all the pieces going out for the job and start to build freight loads. The load is basically a group of lot pieces for the job and a specific trailer. A job could have multiple loads for it and the loads should only consist of the jobs pieces that are assigned.

I am struggling with deciding the ARs from the entities I think I have (customer, project, job, load, lot, lot piece). My biggest invariant I can see is just gating off lot pieces and or projects/jobs having the wrong customer's pieces assigned to it.

For instance if someone wants to go in and change the customer for a lot and its lot pieces - I can check to see if a jobId or projectId has been assigned to any of the pieces and block the request. To avoid bi-directional relationship the project and job entities don't reference the lot piece. But that is an issue if someone wants to change a projects customer I can't block that in the project AR because I don't know if lot pieces have been assigned or not.

Ignoring that UML might not be following best practices this is roughly the shape I am seeing of my entities.

[image]